# @PropertySource not picking the correct property file

Tags: spring-boot, properties, environment

**@PropertySource not picking the correct property file**

Here is my complete code :

**pom.xml**

```
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PropertySource</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
connection_Url=jdbc:oracle://localhost:3306/Prod
driver_Class=OracleDriver
user_Name=Prod
password=ProdPassword
```

**db.properties**

```
connection_Url=jdbc:MySQl://localhost:3306/Test
driver_Class=MySQLDriver
user_Name=Test
password=TestPassword
```

**Both the properties files are available inside src/main/resources directory**

**DataSource.java**

```
public class DataSource {

    private String connectionURL;
    private String driverClass;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    getters/setters
}
```

**DataSourceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:db.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class DataSourceConfig {

    //    Version-1

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setConnectionURL(environment.getProperty("connection_Url"));
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getProperty("driver_Class"));
        dataSource.setUserName(environment.getProperty("user_Name"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    //    Version-2

    /*
    @Value("${connection_Url}")
    private String connectionURL;

    @Value("${driver_Class}")
    private String driverClass;

    @Value("${user_Name}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setConnectionURL(connectionURL);
        dataSource.setDriverClass(driverClass);
        dataSource.setUserName(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }*/
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        DataSource dataSource = context.getBean(DataSource.class);

        System.out.println(dataSource.getConnectionURL());
        System.out.println(dataSource.getDriverClass());
        System.out.println(dataSource.getUserName());
        System.out.println(dataSource.getPassword());
    }
}
```

And here is the output which is same for both version-1 and version-2 as mentioned in DataSourceConfig.java file

```
jdbc:oracle://localhost:3306/Prod
OracleDriver
Prod
ProdPassword
```

It shows that the @PropertySource annotation used in DataSourceConfig class is not picking the correct properties file which is "db.properties" file

**How can i read properties from db.properties file in this case.**

Comment: It appears that you want to have profile based properties. Why not use `application-environment.properties` and then pass the profile at the startup and Spring Boot will use the corresponding properties file.

Comment: Irrespective of profile, i want to instruct my application to read properties from a specific file. In this case "db.properties" file. How can i do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties files are read in very particular order as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

So `application.properties` takes precedence over the properties you are reading via `@PropertySource` and as a result, your `db.properties` is being overwritten as both properties files have the same keys.

Change the property `keys` in your `db.properties` and it should work fine.